# Passing a JSON object to a remote LESS compiler to use as LESS variables

Tags: javascript, json, less

I have an admin panel where users customize the look of a static website (mostly fonts and colors). This panel generate a JSON object with the user values. What I would need to do is passing this JSON to the LESS compiler, so that it can dynamically generate a CSS file from a LESS one using the JSON content as LESS variables. The filename should be different every time, something line file-ID.css (the ID is for the user and it could be passed via JSON too).

Is it technically possible (without extending LESS)? I noticed, for example,  that you can pass functions to the parser object when you create it, could I use this functions to evaluate the JSON and passing the variables to the compiler?

Obviously I don't need to know the details, just if it is doable and possibly some link to   related information if you have it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to do what I was trying to accomplish was to use a server side LESS library like PHPLESS to parse the variables from the JSON before compiling. Regular LESS compiler doesn't allow to dynamically inject variables.

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge the LESS compiler doesn't support any other input than LESS. It would be trivial to make your own pre-parser that mixes-in the variables from JSON .. not even a parser, more of a string-replacer.